# Array property initialization

Tags: c#, properties, initialization

How can I initialize an array property?

Tried this:

```
feeds = new List<Feed>();
feeds.Add(new Feed() { Names = { "Cluj Approach", "Cluj Tower" }, Frequencies = { 117.25 } });
```

with the Feed class:

```
class Feed
{
    public string[] Names { get; set; }
    public float[] Frequencies { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

and it says it can't initialize an object of type string[] with a collection initializer.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Make it a `List<string>` instead and make sure to initialize it with an empty list, if you really need to use the collection initializer.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
feeds.Add(new Feed() { Names = new[] { "Cluj Approach", "Cluj Tower" }, Frequencies = new[] { 117.25f } });
```

Also note f in `117.25f`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually `new` up the array, rather than *just* using braces:

```
new Feed() { Names = new string[] { "Cluj Approach", "Cluj Tower" } //...
```

You can at most simplify it to:

```
new Feed() { Names = new [] { "Cluj Approach", "Cluj Tower" } //...
```

and have the type inferred.

Comment: You can also remove the redundant `()` to simplify a little bit more.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I prefer to leave it; it's much clearer to read and makes it much less likely to confuse object initializers with collection initializers.

Comment: Weird preference, but alright haha. Personally I see it as useless clutter (Quite easy to see the difference between `new A{}` and `new List<A>{}`) and it's enhanced by my IDE which displays redundant/unreachable code so dark it looks like I have 3 spaces.

Comment: But I think you can use collection initializers with constructor arguments, as in `new HashSet<int>(myEuqalityComparer) { 2, 4, 6, 8, }`, or am I wrong? What is the logic in keeping redundant `()` in one case but not in another?